# PersistanceContext on NonServlet class

Tags: jpa, ejb-3.1

I have the following...

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;
  ...
}

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class DeviceRegistrationPersister {
  @PersistenceContext(unitName="deviceReg")
  private EntityManager em;
  ...
}
```

The first one gets the entity manager just fine, however, the second the entity manager is null. Can someone help with what is going on?

Comment: My persistance.xml does not include the DeviceRegistrationPersister because it is not a JPA class so I didn't think I needed it there. But neither is the Servlet so that is why I didn't think it was an issue. As for the error it is just a null pointer exception when I try to access the property (because the wiring never works). I can't provide a stacktrace due to some sensitivity (I can but I would have to redact stuff). But there is nothing strange there. Just seems as though one gets wired and the other doesn't.

Comment: Magicano is asking where the unitName="deviceReg" is coming from.  In the working example, you don't have it defined, while in the stateless bean, you have a name defined.  Check that the name actually corresponds to a persistence unit in your persistence.xml.  Otherwise leave it blank so that it defaults.

Comment: That is what I am trying to say it isn't included in the persistence.xml. I tried removing it and it seems to have the same response.